# Почему возникает ошибка "Не удается зарегистрировать модуль hresult -2147024770"?

Tags: windowsinstaller, wix, msi

Разрабатываю msi установщик. В установщик с помощью merge встроен msm файл Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x64.msm так

```
<?if $(var.PLATFORMTYPE) = Win32 ?>
<DirectoryRef Id="SystemFolder" DiskId ="1">
   <Merge Id="VC140_CRT" SourceFile="Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x86.msm" Language ="0"/> 
</DirectoryRef>
<?endif?>
<?if $(var.PLATFORMTYPE) = x64 ?>
<DirectoryRef Id="System64Folder" DiskId ="1">
  <Merge Id="VC140_CRT" SourceFile="Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x64.msm" Language ="0"/>
</DirectoryRef>
<?endif?>
```

Этот msm модуль устанавливается только, если в системе отсутствует Visual C++ Runtime Libs. Это реализовано так ([Образец](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564829/wix-if-else-condition-using-registry))

```
  <?if $(var.PLATFORMTYPE) = Win32 ?>

  <Property Id="REGISTERVC140" Value="0">
    <RegistrySearch Id="RegisterVC140_CRT" 
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86" 
                    Name="Installed" 
                    Root="HKLM" 
                    Type="raw" 
                    Win64="no"/>
  </Property>

<?else?>

  <Property Id="REGISTERVC140" Value="0">
    <RegistrySearch Id="RegisterVC140_CRT" 
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64" 
                    Name="Installed" 
                    Root="HKLM" 
                    Type="raw" 
                    Win64="yes"/>
  </Property>    

<?endif?>

<Feature Id="VC140_CRTFeature" Title="!(loc.ProductName)" Level="0">
  <Condition Level="1"><![CDATA[REGISTERVC140 > "0"]]></Condition>
  <MergeRef Id="VC140_CRT"/>
</Feature>
```

Однако, в ходе установки, я получаю ошибку "Не удалось зарегистрировать модуль SafeuseShell.dll. HRESULT -2147024770". Почему возникает данная ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: этот код - это "The specified module could not be found. " То есть, не может найти dll.

Comment: Извиняюсь! Ты перевел код ошибки в шестнадцатеричный формат?

Comment: Ищите у себя утилиту errlook, она может быть где то здесь `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\errlook.exe`